# how to convert a .BAI file into .TSV file using python script?

Tags: python-3.x, pysam

We have a file with **"BAI"** format and need to convert it to **"TSV"** format using `python script`.

We need a `python script` that converts **.BAI** file into **"TSV"**.

I am a beginner at python scripting.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: as im beginner i dont know where to start. i just needed the TSV file from a BAI File. i have nothing to do with python programming.